# matlab divide an image according to the user input

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, divide

I have an Image : 
[image: 3 FIGURES]

I want to manually divide the image into the parts as show below: 
The division of the image should be user controlled. I should be able to take the user input of the rectangular squares in which I am trying to divide the Image.

The output is shown below : 
[image: 3 FIGURES]

How can I do this in matlab?

After operating on the individual images can I join them back together to make the image as one ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`imrect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) to create an interactive rectangular selection tool on top of the input image. Look closely at the second example.

Once the user has selected a rectangel, you can use `imcrop` to get the corresponding part.
Saving the relative position of the selected rectangle (i.e., the position vector `[x y w h]`) you can then "re-embbed" the part into the original image at the same location.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I will try it out. I thought about simply using imcrop only.

Comment: Excuse me but could you clarify why in the second example they have used the wait command ?

Comment: @roni - please try and run the commands yourself and see what is their impact and effect. `wait` is used to stop the command pormpt until the user finishes his selection.

Comment: I finally got it and posted the answer.

Comment: How come imrect can select areas outside the image ?

Comment: @roni it does not. the area selected is an intersection between the `crop_area` and the image rect.

Comment: No I meant the area selected is correct. However if we drag the rectangle outside the image boundaries still there is no error shown. As well , the position selected by the rect i.e, [x y w h], x & y may give negative values for the coordinates selected outside the image area.

Please look into it and give your thoughts.

Comment: could you give me some ideas on how to embedd back the images ?

Comment: Please give me your suggestions!

Comment: @roni what have **you** tried? have you looked for solutions in SO? I'm almost certain such a question was asked here before. Don't expect me to do your work for you.

Comment: Hi again. could you explain to me why when I select a rectangular area with the rect command in matlab do I get values in floating point no? I mean should not all be integers as images are considered as a matrix in matlab?

Comment: Hi again. There is a slight problem that I get while using imrect. Suppose there is a figure of size 128x128. If by the imrect function I select the whole image and read the handle h, I get the values of [x,y,w,h] = [0.5,0.5,128,128]. Why is it so ? 

Should not it be [x,y,w,h] = [1,1,128,128]

Can you help me ?

Comment: @roni images are indeed represented as matrices and pixels are addressed using **integer** indices. However, when you move a mouse over the screen, it might happen that the location of the mouse can achieve sub-pixel accuracy. For your purpose I suppose you can `round` the rect you get to avoid this sub-pixel effect.

Comment: No the rounding of actually does not seem to work. Somehow imrect works strangely : the physical screen pixels do not match image pixels one-to-one. How can i force it to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it . Thanks !

```
Img = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure();
imshow(Img);
h = imrect();
crop_area = wait(h);
cropped = imcrop(Img, crop_area);
imshow(cropped);
```

This works well.